# My Visual C++ compiler compiles out of date source

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, native

I'm a beginner starting to use Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010 for Windows Programming. I've created a new C++ application using native code, not managed or MFC. I had Visual Studio create for me the basic windows code to create one window with simple menus (chat.cpp). I modified this file and I was able to compile correctly and see my changes take effect.

Now I've added one more source file to the solution (intro.cpp) which I include in my header and call from within chat.cpp. This seems to work just fine, but with one problem. The compiler doesn't seem to be applying my code changes occasionally: I make various edits, recompile, and the "old" code seems to be running. Then, after a while, after I make only a tiny modification, the compiler seems to "catch up" and it runs the new code including all the previous changes I had made.

Is there some kind of cache? Do I need to tell the compiler which files to compile and which ones to just link from object files? Did I make a mistake when I added the file to the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `intro.cpp` have a header file? is that in your solution too?

It's hard for me to imagine that this area of such a mature IDE has a bug here, so I would examine your file list first.  Make sure that the Solution Explorer shows **all** the files you have added and are editing. This is the list that VS uses to determine rebuild is needed.

EDIT: I admit it's not clear to me from your description why it would fail right now.  However, typically header files do not include code, it works the other way around (except for class template header files, such as the STL headers).  There is some discussion about pros and cons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193864/pros-cons-of-putting-all-code-in-header-files-in-c).  The most compelling argument to me in favour of code including headers rather than vice versa is that the header file contains the *interface*, while the code file contains the *implementation*.

I would try restructuring your code to a more traditional structure where intro.cpp includes intro.h and any others it needs, and the same with chat.cpp.  Then your compilation units are intro.cpp and chat.cpp, and they depend on the associated header files, so provided they are properly listed in the SOlution Explorer, all should work.  You can clean up the build dependencies to avoid dups and reduce build time once you have it working as you wish.

Comment: I have a 'chat.h' file which includes both 'chat.cpp' and 'intro.cpp' files. There is no separate 'intro.h' file. I'm not sure I'm doing the file separation correctly, and it certainly seems to be my own problem, not the compiler's; I would expect the compiler to know how to handle this. The solution explorer shows 'intro.cpp' under the 'Source Files' list correctly, just like it shows 'chat.cpp'.